# GCP: Can I list permissions assigned to custom role using gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Is there any way to list the permissions associated with a (custom) role in Google Cloud Platform IAM using `gcloud`? I can find how to list the roles, but not the permissions associated with a given role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can list the permissions associated with a role using this command. Replace the role name with your custom role name.

`gcloud iam roles describe roles/editor`

Documentation: [gcloud iam roles describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/describe)

Comment: This does not seem to work with the custom roles. The error is as follows  
`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.iam.roles.describe) Invalid value for [ROLE_ID]: The role id that starts with 'roles/' only stands for curated role. Should not specify the project or organization for curated roles`

Comment: @noob - What command are you running? The command in my answer is correct. If you mean that you created a custom role, then use the custom role name instead of `roles/editor`

Comment: This is the command I am using - `gcloud iam roles describe roles/CustomRole --project=my-project` this works for the curated roles, but not for the custom roles for me.

Comment: @Remove `roles/` and use the custom role name. You will need to look up the role ID and use the last part as in **MyCustomRole43**. In my answer `roles/editor` is the role name, the `roles` portion is not part of a custom role except when specifying the full role ID. You will also need to specify the project for custom roles as they are project specific. All of this is documented.

Comment: Thanks, removing the `roles/` prefix worked.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the other answer is the one with the most upvotes, doesn't actually answer the question about getting a custom role.

To follow up the above comment:

Custom role at organization level: `gcloud iam roles describe [roleId] --organization=[organizationId]`

Custom role at the project level: `gcloud iam roles describe [roleId] --project=[projectId]`

Comment: You are correct and your answer is helpful. I should have provided more details in my answer and not relied on additional comments. Many of the CLI commands require understanding the options, so I try to convince others to read the documentation by providing a link. Details can evolve over time.

Answer (score 1):

for predefined role:
`gcloud iam roles describe roles/[roleid]`

for custom role:
`gcloud iam roles describe [roleid] --project=[projectid]`